# Don't works "self" parameter for "listByUser" method

Tags: google-api, blogger, google-apis-explorer

I can't get list of blogs via this method https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/blogs/listByUser

I replace "userId" by keyword "self", how it's described on the documentation page:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/userId/blogs > https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs

Get error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}],"code":500,"message":"Backend Error"}}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code I just ran a test call and its working fine.    https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/blogger/v3/blogger.blogs.listByUser?userId=self&_h=3&

Comment: I am trying direct from the site. Look it - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eiktIuwkxckwkcx-Np2TnsXzfHBDmVqb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I must remark about other API methods, much of them work without error. Can't get list of blogs. I think it is bug on the server side, because I have not standard amount of blogs, blogs number about 58 (for themes developing, testing, etc...).

Comment: Yes, of course. On the page via Google APIs Explorer or in my project I get this error. Link to gif, I am record all my steps for you and upload to GDisk.

Comment: don't try to use that to validate the API use the API explorer Link I gave you its more stable

Comment: The result is the same, I got error. Need to invite an engineer from Google. It's Google servers bug. I think it's reason:
"I have not standard amount of blogs, blogs number about 58..."

Comment: @rekzi the problem is indeed with the number of blogs. When I ran this query on a Blogger account with more than 50 blogs present in it, then the request failed (Similar to your error, Refer to https://i.imgur.com/a0OoR9q.png ). But when running this request from a Blogger account with 4-5 blogs present, then the user's blogs list was returned without any issue

Comment: I get error from other project too, where needed get blogs list to select one from them. It is IFTTT blogger service (if you familiar with it).
I can not find contacts of developers or any bug tracker Blogger API for report.

Comment: Yes, I understand your use case (This is common in mobile apps, where they ask to choose the Blogger blog before creating a new post in the chosen blog). I would suggest raising this issue in Blogger Developer Forum ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bloggerdev ) and see if any Blogger engineer picks it from there. Some of the Blogger Engineers are sometimes also present in the main Blogger Forum ( https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/blogger ). Mainly it is a bit of hit and trial on those forums but if it's picked up by the right person, then they will surely look into it.

Comment: I will find someone to ping at Google

Comment: Also, on investigating a bit further, I noticed that this is happening on the official Android app as well. ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.blogger&hl=en )  When I log in to my account with more than 50+ blogs, then it gives me the error that this account doesn't have any blogs (likely a faulty error message as I am able to access all my blogs in the same account via the web interface. Refer to https://i.imgur.com/gWlVyTD.png) But when I log in to an account with lesser number of blogs, then things work out fine (Refer to https://i.imgur.com/FZUCK73.png)